# How can I fill a map with a vector?

Tags: pointers, vector, shared-ptr, smart-pointers, stdmap

I have the following test code:

```
class Person{};


shared_ptr<Person> sp1;
shared_ptr<Person> sp2;
shared_ptr<Person> sp3;

vector<shared_ptr<Person>> members = {sp1,sp2,sp3};

map<string, shared_ptr<Person>> mymap;
```

How can I set the vector `members` to the second element of `mymap`? I tried with `for` and `copy` .

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`map` is an associative container, so you need to specify the key in `string` type to associate it to the `shared_ptr<Person>`. I don't know what you need, but the following loop should work:

```cpp
for (size_t i = 0; i < members.size(); ++i) {
  const std::string key = "sp" + std::to_string(i+1);
  mymap[key] = members[i];
}
```